# Connect Angular (nginx) with backend on Docker RUN

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, devops, docker-container

In fact, everything it's already connected. I need to make it dynamic (maybe this is not the concept). I'm working on a system that consists of two separate and independent containers: NET Core Backend & Angular Frontend (nginx).

The Angular app create connection URLs using `environment` variables, that means that de `baseURL` variable contains the URL for the server-backend connection. For local purposes this is `http://localhost:5000`. Everything works great: CORS is accepting calls, JWTs are issued correctly and the WebAPI it's returning values.

This product it's meant to work on a single VM server for every client. Every client will have it's own server IP to access the app. The `baseURL` for the frontend Angular app is hardcoded in `environment.prod`, but using this approach I'd have to change the `baseURL` in `environment.prod` for every implementation (client) and this, i think, it's not the right approach.

I've tried to make this work using a `host` alias and passing that alias with `--link` flag in Docker run, but didn't work. Something like:

**environment.prod.ts (Angular)**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://backendalias:5000'
};
```

Running with the command:

```sh
docker run --rm -d -p 5500:80 --link=backend_container:backendalias frontendimage
```

But this can't reach the backend and no connection is established.

I need to make this implementation more dynamic so I don't have to change the codebase for every client.

Is this approach right? Do i need to change Docker network configuration via `--network` flag? What do you suggest for this kind of products/systems?

I want to control this (ideally) with Docker running commands.

Comment: Why don't you try to spin up your containers using `docker-compose` and use `Nginx` for routing. If you want I can give you that solution. That would be a generic solution and you don't need to setup using `env variables`

Comment: That would be awesome @DupinderSingh. I'm open to any approach, in fact, it's the idea  of this question. If you could post it over here it would be even more practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create one generic example to solve your problem

https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv

Follow this GitHub repo, have a look at the readme.md I tried to describe each and every step which will help you to communicate Angular UI app with backend service. and I added one more addition feature "The remote debugging".

Have a look, if any about, please ask

Comment: Thanks Dupinder! Very helpful and well explained. I think this question will be a great resource for the community. I'll continue asking & discussing further details in the repository... so, be patient. Thanks again!

Comment: I have enabled springboot `https` self-signed, can you publish the changes which I should do in order to make it self-signed ssl?